# find a solution to this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi there is an exercice that i need to do. I'm new with differential equation i would like you to help me a little bit.

A culture of living tissue grows until it reaches a maximum area M cm^2 .The area A(t) of ​​the fabric at time t is defined by :

$$
\frac {dA}{dt}= k*\sqrt A  (1-\frac {A}{M})
$$
where k is a constant

a) Find the solution of the differential equation with $A = u^2$  
b) Show that the rate of increase of the area reaches a maximum at $A = M/3$

Until now I have done that :

$$
A(t) = \frac {4M^2}{(c1*M+k(M-1)t)^2}
$$

$$
\frac {dA}{dt}= 2u*\frac {du}{dt}
$$
but i don't know what to do after.

Thank you

Comment: What is $a(t)$ and where did it come from? Did you mean $A(t)$? Also: is your lower case $m$ the same as $M$?

Comment: yes sorry i have edited it. I found this solution by using my TI Nspire by using deSolve() i don't know if i need it...

Comment: Rather than working directly with the solution, you can solve part b by differentiating your expression for $\frac{dA}{dt}$ with respect to $A$ and setting it equal to zero. As for the actually finding the solution, their suggestion was to let $A=u^2$ and solve for $u$ and back-substitute. (Of course the result should be consistent with your computer solution.)

Answer (score 3):

Possible hint: If $f(y'(x),y(x))=0$ for some function rule $f$ and you see  that $y'=g(y)$ which $g$ is free of the independent variable $t$ or $x$, then you can write $\frac{dy}{g(y)}=dx$ and then integrate properly from both sides.

Answer (score 1):

for the first question :
$$\frac { dA }{ dt } =k*\sqrt { A } (1-\frac { A }{ M } )\\ A={ u }^{ 2 }\\ 2u\frac { du }{ dt } =ku\left( 1-\frac { { u }^{ 2 } }{ M }  \right) \\ 2\frac { du }{ dt } =k\left( 1-\frac { { u }^{ 2 } }{ M }  \right) \\ 2\int { \frac { du }{ 1-\frac { { u }^{ 2 } }{ M }  }  } =k\int { dt } \\ \sqrt { M } \ln { \left| \frac { \sqrt { M } +u }{ \sqrt { M } -u }  \right| =kt } +C\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ $$

Comment: thank you but i don't understand  why this $$\\ 2\int { \frac { du }{ 1-\frac { { u }^{ 2 } }{ M }  }  }  $$ it not giving you that $$ -\sqrt{m} * ln(\frac{u- \sqrt{m}} {u+ \sqrt{m}})$$

Comment: The - sign allows you to swap numerator and denominator under the ln. Then you forgot the absolute value that lets you adjust also the subtraction at the denominator.

Comment: it is beacuse from the integral list we know that : $\int { \frac { du }{ { a }^{ 2 }-{ u }^{ 2 } } =\frac { 1 }{ 2a } \ln { \left( \frac { a+u }{ a-u }  \right)  }  } $

Comment: thank you very much guys. Do you have a tips for b)

Comment: i got it! if you want to see my answer i will write it

Comment: yes please,i would be greatful)

Answer (score 0):

Put $A = u^2$ everywhere:
$$ \frac {d(u^2)}{dt}= k \sqrt {u^2}  (1-\frac {u^2}{M}) $$
This gives:
$$ 2u \frac {du}{dt}= k u (1-\frac {u^2}{M})  = u k - u^3\frac{k}{M}$$
which is the same as
$$ \frac {du}{dt} =  \frac{k}{2}(1  - \frac{u^2}{M})$$

Can you solve for $u(t)$ from this point?